# antd-img-crop - Skip crop/resize if the image being uploaded in .svg format

Tags: reactjs, svg, antd

I have implemented  antd-img-crop on image upload for my react app. I want to skip the crop/resize if the image file selected is .svg format as the svg file gets corrupted after uploading.

Answer (score 1):

**beforeCrop** prop of **ImgCrop** component give you access to the file object, using which you can validate the type of file that's being uploaded.

```
<ImgCrop beforeCrop={file => console.log(file)}>
    <Upload>+ Add image</Upload>
</ImgCrop>
```